# Java - If Statement for Connection

Tags: java, if-statement, connection

I'm building an application that harvests data from the web. But if there is not a connection, I want to display a message, however if there is a connection I want the program to carry on.

In pseudo code it'd be something like:

```
if (connection == true) {
   // Get Data
} else {
   // Output error message
}
```

But how would I actually find out if there is a connection to start with to do this?

Comment: What kind of object is connection? It can't be a `boolean` for sure!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java for possible answers.

Comment: that code looks fine to me. what is `connection`? you need to look at the documentation for whatever network/sockets library you're using. it will indicate how to handle failed connection attempts.

Comment: There will be no connection, unless you make one. The APIs you use to make one will throw exceptions when something goes wrong.

Comment: 'connection' isn't anything. It's just a format I would imagine it taking, I'm asking on here because I don't know how to perform the if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the tags it is an internet connection, you would just do like this

```
try {
    //open connection
} catch(Exception e) {
    //connection failed
}
```

Comment: Catch the specific exception thrown, not just Exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to a web address you would probably want to create a [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) then call `openConnection` to get a [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).  Now with your `URLConnection` you can do:

```
try {
    connection.connect();

    // Get your data here.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle your error message here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing connection with null(only if its an object). Like this-

```
if(connection!=null)
```