# Instantly check Internet connectivity

Tags: android

is there any broadcast receiver ( or services )that continuously check internet connectivity during the app are stay running. so whenever there are loose connectivity i got some message of loose connectivity.
i know `ConnectivityManager`

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```

is the class by which we can check that is there connect with internet or not ? but i need to check instantly...

Comment: open www.google.com and you can get instant internet connectivity... :)

Comment: ConnectivityManager is probably your best bet, I have tried looking for it before but couldn't find anything. check out this question it has some answers with minor improvements for checking connectivity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Comment: @user1129443 - Hey relax friends just wanted to make you divert from your stress.. hope you find your solution soon...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if internet connection is present in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

this try code is working

```
public static boolean checkConnection(Context mContext) {

        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @PareshMayani exactly .. . .. . +1

Comment: @user1129443 check `update` section in [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-check-internet-connection/) tutorial.

Comment: @user1129443 then write this code inside the Background service.

Comment: @PareshMayani i had idea of it but i need to go through broadcasting services i have put this code in services and its working fine...

Comment: @user1129443 glad that you got solution!! Cheers

Comment: if info.isroaming() return true. Else, return true. Why check if it's roaming then?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a broadcast with an specific action:

`IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, filter);`

Comment: Yo can define the receiver in the manifest if you want or maybe you want to define the broadcast in the activity that you want.

Something like:

`private BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
                        //DO Something
  }
 };`

Comment: This broadcast advise when the connectivity CHANGE!! it don't receive an intent every N seconds. Maybe you can save the connectivity (on/off) at the start of the app, and then update ir with the receiver. And you will only read the state that you save.

Answer (score 0):

use ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission and just make a connected method

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untill You are developing an Application that displays network states then try mugging up with ConnectivityManager and other broadcasts.

If the case is (which is mostly usual) you need to do some network based operation like fetching some data from any server.

I don't go for checking  network states 
but rely on UnknownHostException or RuntimeException or etc that get throws when you make a request that tells me "hey network is not available".

This i feel is more better approach as compare to do network check before making api request.

1. no need of additional code of connectivity manager.
2. plus what if case developer saves value of connection not available and not updating it  and uses it after some time. so its error prone
3. It will be like a check at exact time when its required and will not effect other operations.
4. Major one case is that for very positive case where device never looses data 
   connectivity. why to run a piece of code which is of no use.

this is just my preference and i am not questioning the existence of ConnectivityManager :) .

Hope it helps somehow either in this or in some other scene.

Comment: and that will be the most Instant Check of Internet Connectivity