# gradle script function to detect offline

Tags: ruby, build, gradle, android-studio

I want to add some code to my settings.gradle file

```
  if (!hasInternetAccess()) {
    startParameter.offline=true
  }
```

to allow gradle-code compilation if my computer has no internetconnection.

does anybody know how a gradle script can implement hasInternetAccess()?

Background: [gradle or android studios compilation fails if the computer has no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gradle+offline)
because it could not look for updated dependencies.

instead of manually invoking gradle with the "--offline" parameter

or adding

```
    startParameter.offline=true
```

to the settings.gradle file
i am looking for a way to automate the configuration

[update]

i followed @opal-s link and added these lines to my settings.gradle file:

```
boolean isReachable = java.net.InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com").isReachable(1500)
print "has internet: " + isReachable
```

in the debug output i always get

```
has internet: false
```

although i can successfully `ping www.google.com`

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java. You can implement it as plain java method.

Comment: Here you will find a working solution to check internet connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922543/why-does-inetaddress-isreachable-return-false-when-i-can-ping-the-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Using `--offline` should result in the behavior you want.