# In Compose for Desktop, how can I keep track of the internet connection status?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

I wanted to constantly check for internet connection status in order to block my Application (with a dialog window informing the issue) until the network is re-established. Since I'm not using Compose for Android, I don't have access to ConnectivityManager class as I've seen been used in other related answers to this question online. How can I achieve this in Compose for Desktop?

Comment: Compose for Desktop is UI framework, it has nothing to do with internet connection. In such cases you need to search for platform-related answers - in this case your platform is JVM, so something like "jvm interner reachability" would give you [How to check if internet connection is present in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Basically Compose for Desktop means that you can use any JVM/Java/Kotlin way of checking for Internet connectivity.

One option would be to use the `NetworkUtils` class provided by the `java.net` package.

```
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.UnknownHostException

fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com")
        address != null && !address.equals("")
    } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
        false
    }
}
```

You are checking if you can reach Google by trying to resolve it's IP address.

Be aware that this approach is not foolproof and there may be cases where the internet is available but the Google website is not reachable (e.g. due to firewall restrictions).