# how can I check whether device can access Internet via active WiFi Connection?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am referring to a situation when device is connected to access point but for some reason is blocked from accessing internet using this AP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like something that can solve the problem:

[How to do a true Java ping from Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448666/how-to-do-a-true-java-ping-from-windows)

[How to check if internet connection is present in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java)

[Detect internet Connection using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139547/detect-internet-connection-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

for check wifi is enabled or not

```
 WifiManager wfManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wfManager.isWifiEnabled())
{
    //Code
}
else  
{
 //Code
 }
```

for check internet connection..

```
public boolean isOnline() 
{
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) 
    {
            //Try This 
            int i =netInfo.getType() ; 
            System.out.println("Net Type ="+i);    

            return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need - state CONNECTED for WiFi connection means that the device is connected to the AP but not necessarily can access Internet

Comment: netInfo.getType() ; try this but exactly i didnt used this so i dont know which value for wifi or mobile internet.. for more info u can follow this link..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType%28%29

Comment: not really, dear... all these API provide info about connection to the AP but there is no way to identify whether it can go any further. Still looking...

Comment: i think its reply only two value so can test one by one using net with wifi n mobile's net.. so u can understand exactly which value for wifi or mobile..

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean connectionAvailable() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need - state CONNECTED for WiFi connection means that the device is connected to the AP but not necessarily can access Internet

Comment: Ok so you want to check that wifi is accessing the internet or not. i have no idea for that.