# My Android application is crashing if it is not connected to wifi

Tags: android

```
package com.example.intracollegeapp;// package name

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


import LibPack.UserInfoLib;
import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class LoginForm extends Activity {
    Button login;
    TextView username;
    TextView password;
    UserInfoLib ui;
    long msgLength;
    long bitLength;
    char msg[];
    long requiredBits;
    long requiredBytes;
    int toPad[];
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "link to server package on which     webservices are stored";
    private static final String URL = "link to wsdl file stored on server";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "IntraCollegeWS";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_form);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butLogin);
        username=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ui= new UserInfoLib();
                ui.userId=username.getText().toString();
                ui.password=getSHA1(password.getText().toString());

                ui=(UserInfoLib)callService(objectToString(ui), "UserLogin", "userInfo");
                //ui=(UserInfoLib)stringToObject(temp);

                if(ui.firstName.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please Verify User Name Or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("NAME :"+ui.firstName);
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainForm.class);
                    i.putExtra("uid", ui);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public long leftRotateBy(long l, int times) {
        return ((l << times) & 0xFFFFFFFFl) | ((l & 0xFFFFFFFFl) >> (32 - times));
    }

    public int getByteAt(int at) {
        if (at < msgLength) {
            return (msg[at]);
        } else {
            at = at - (int) msgLength;
            return toPad[at];
        }
    }

    public void padBits(String pass) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n");

        msg = pass.toCharArray();
        msgLength = msg.length;
        bitLength = msgLength * 8;

        System.out.println("Msg Bit Length: " + bitLength);
        System.out.println("MSg Byte Length: " + msgLength);
        System.out.println("Required Minimum Bits: " + (bitLength + 65));

        long remainder = (bitLength + 65) % 512;
        System.out.println("Mod (Bits): " + remainder);


        if (remainder == 0) {
            requiredBits = 65;
            System.out.println("No Padding Needed.");
        } else {
            requiredBits = (512 - remainder) + 65;
            System.out.println(requiredBits + " Bits Padding Needed.");
        }

        requiredBytes = requiredBits / 8;
        toPad = new int[(int) requiredBytes];
        System.out.println("Required Bits: " + requiredBits);
        System.out.println("Required Bytes: " + requiredBytes);

        // manually append 1 to start of pad bits...
        toPad[0] = 0x80;
        for (int i = 1; i < requiredBytes - 8; i++) {
            toPad[i] = 0;
        }

        long temp = bitLength;
        for (int i = (int) (requiredBytes - 1); i >= (int) (requiredBytes - 8); i--) {
            int t = (int) (temp & 0xff);
            temp = temp >> 8;
        toPad[i] = t;
        }

        System.out.println("TO PAD: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < requiredBytes; i++) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(toPad[i]) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public String getSHA1(String pass) {
        int kconst[] = new int[]{
                0x5A827999,
                0x6ED9EBA1,
                0x8F1BBCDC,
                0xCA62C1D6};

        long h0 = 0x67452301;
        long h1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
        long h2 = 0x98BADCFE;
        long h3 = 0x10325476;
        long h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;
        long a, b, c, d, e;
        padBits(pass);

        long totalLength = msgLength + requiredBytes;
        System.out.println("TOTAL LENGTH: " + totalLength);
        System.out.println("BLOCKS: " + (totalLength / 8));

        long w[] = new long[80];
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) totalLength; i += 64) {
            for (int j = i, kk = 0; j < (i + 64); j += 4, kk++) {
                w[kk] = 0xffffffffl & ((getByteAt(j) << 24) | (getByteAt(j + 1) << 16) | (getByteAt(j + 2) << 8) | (getByteAt(j + 3)));
                //System.out.println("W[" + kk + "]: " + Long.toHexString(w[kk]));
            }

            for (int kk = 16; kk < 80; kk++) {
                w[kk] = (w[kk - 3] ^ w[kk - 8] ^ w[kk - 14] ^ w[kk - 16]);
                w[kk] = leftRotateBy(w[kk], 1);
                //System.out.println("W[" + kk + "]: " + Long.toHexString(w[kk]));
            }
            a = h0;
            b = h1;
            c = h2;
            d = h3;
            e = h4;

            long temp = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
                temp = leftRotateBy(a, 5) + ((b & c) | ((~b) & d)) + e + w[t] + kconst[0];
                temp &= 0xFFFFFFFFl;
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = leftRotateBy(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = temp;
            }

            for (int t = 20; t < 40; t++) {
                temp = leftRotateBy(a, 5) + (b ^ c ^ d) + e + w[t] + kconst[1];
                temp &= 0xFFFFFFFFl;
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = leftRotateBy(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = temp;
            }

            for (int t = 40; t < 60; t++) {
                temp = leftRotateBy(a, 5) + ((b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d)) + e + w[t] + kconst[2];
                temp &= 0xFFFFFFFFl;
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = leftRotateBy(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = temp;
            }

            for (int t = 60; t < 80; t++) {
                temp = leftRotateBy(a, 5) + (b ^ c ^ d) + e + w[t] + kconst[3];
                temp &= 0xFFFFFFFFl;
                e = d;
                d = c;
                c = leftRotateBy(b, 30);
                b = a;
                a = temp;
            }

            h0 = (h0 + a) & 0xFFFFFFFFl;
            h1 = (h1 + b) & 0xFFFFFFFFl;
            h2 = (h2 + c) & 0xFFFFFFFFl;
            h3 = (h3 + d) & 0xFFFFFFFFl;
            h4 = (h4 + e) & 0xFFFFFFFFl;
        }
        return Long.toHexString(h0) + Long.toHexString(h1) + Long.toHexString(h2) + Long.toHexString(h3) + Long.toHexString(h4);


    }

    Object callService(String INPUT_DATA, String METHOD_NAME, String PARAMETER_NAME){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName(PARAMETER_NAME);
        pi.setValue(INPUT_DATA);
        pi.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(pi);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            String resp = resultsRequestSOAP.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("return");

            return stringToObject(resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    Object stringToObject(String inp){
        byte b[] = Base64.decode(inp);
        Object ret = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            ret = (Object) in.readObject(); 
            bis.close();
            in.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NOT DE-SERIALIZABLE: " + e);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    String objectToString(Object obj){
        byte[] b = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
            out.writeObject(obj);
            b = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NOT SERIALIZABLE: " + e);
        }         
        return Base64.encode(b);
    }





}
```

/*  i have developed an android application which connects to server for login purpose. For connection i have used ksoap2 library. Intracollege webservice is stored on server. The application works fine when connected to server using wifi. if it is not connected to wifi it displays message "application is crashed" and then application stops working.
    I only want to display a simple message "Application is not connected to server" if it is not connected to server using wifi.*/

Comment: check internet connection in login button clicklistener.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973290/check-wifi-and-gps-isconnected-or-not-in-android    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840760/how-can-i-check-whether-device-can-access-internet-via-active-wifi-connection

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

```
public boolean isNet()
{
 boolean status=false;
 String line;
 try
 {
     URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     while(( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
     {
     }
     status=true;
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("ex in isNet : "+ex.toString());
    if(ex.toString().equals("java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com"))
        status=false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
return status;
}


if(status==true)
        {
        //Do your operation
        }
        else
            show("No Internet Connection.");
```

When status is true do your login process.Otherwise show message "Application is not connected to server".

Answer (score 0):

To check for the internet connection try this out

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, this will help you :

Initialize in the class where you want to check network availability.

```
OtherUtils otherUtils = new OtherUtils();
if (!otherUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

Add below class:

```
    public class OtherUtils{
    Context context;
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
                this.context = context;

               ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
               if (connectivity == null) {
                //  boitealerte(this.getString(R.string.alertNoNetwork),"getSystemService rend null");
               } else {
                  NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                  if (info != null) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                           return true;
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
               return false;
            }
    }
```

This will surely help you.