# Checking if PC has internet connectivity using Java

Tags: java, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect internet Connection using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139547/detect-internet-connection-using-java)
>   [How to check if internet connection is present in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005/how-to-check-if-internet-connection-is-present-in-java)

Following is my code to check whether PC has internet connectivity or not:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connected = true;
}
catch(IOException ioe){
    connected = false;
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to know whether this a reliable and best method? Whenever there is no internet connectivity, an acception would be thrown and the value of boolean variable connected equals `false`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect internet Connection using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139547/detect-internet-connection-using-java) and [How to check if internet connection is present in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402005)

Comment: Hint: `ping www.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: This method is not reliable! The value of connected is always true. Can someone explain me why!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [InetAddress.isReachable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable)

Comment: How it is better than current method?

Comment: The specific intention of the method is to check if an address is reachable. Why duplicate functionality that already exists? Also, I'd recommend not just pinging google, but actually check the site you need to access.

Comment: Actually I don't want to access any particular website. I just want to know whether PC can connect to internet or not!

Comment: I tried using InetAddress.isReachable(); but it always returns false! Can anyone expalin?!